# Why don't I need to use state updater function with array?

Tags: reactjs

I have a program in React that renders a list of random numbers, starting with an empty array and adding one new random number at a time.

I'm wondering, why both approaches for updating state work effectively in this case.
Firstly, using state updater function, I can do:

```
const addRandomNumber = () => {
        const rannum = getRandomInt()
        setNumbers(nums => [...nums, rannum])
}
```

but I can also just directly pass in the new array:

```
setNumbers([...numbers, rannum])
```

And either way, the array remembers the former list of numbers, before adding the new one.

I thought we needed to pass in the updater function when a new state depends on the former state? Here, the new state being the new array with old values and new random value each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the function version of the state setter if you might not have the *most current* version of the state in the outer closure.

For example, if `addRandomNumber` runs on click, and only on click, the state will get updated immediately, and the new render will result in a new `addRandomNumber` click handler (with the updated state).

But if `addRandomNumber` may not have the most current state in its closure - for example, in a `setInterval` on mount, then using the function version is necessary:

```js
// fails:
const App = () => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = React.useState([]);
  const addRandomNumber = () => {
    setNumbers([...numbers, Math.round(Math.random() * 10)]);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(addRandomNumber, 2000);
  }, []);
  return numbers.join(',');
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

```js
// works:
const App = () => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = React.useState([]);
  const addRandomNumber = () => {
    setNumbers(numbers => [...numbers, Math.round(Math.random() * 10)]);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(addRandomNumber, 2000);
  }, []);
  return numbers.join(',');
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

If the (lexical code) location that the state is set will always have the most up-to-date version of the state in its outer scope, then there's no need for the function version.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the React docs might be of more use to you: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Especially this part that says:

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

Essentially in common use cases this probably won't be an issue but in situations where many calls are made at the same time you can't guarantee that the state values have been updated yet before you do your calculation.